# evaluate the vector sum

Tags: calculus

Question: Let A, B, C and D denote four distinct points in the plane. Let uAB denote the
vector pointing from A to B, and similarly uBC points from B to C while uCD points from C to D
and uDA points from D back to A. 
Evaluate the vector sum
uAB + uBC + uCD + uDA:

I dont understand what this question is asking. what is there to evaluate if all im given is 4 points without coordinates?

Comment: The answer doesn't depend on the vectors.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is general. It is similar to asking, what is the sum of x, y, and z? The answer is simply x + y + z.

Comment: would i just give a b c and d coordinates like A is <$x_1$, $y_1$> and B <$x_2$, $y_2$> and so on and then add up those coordinates?

Comment: No, the correct answer is uAB + uBC + uCD + uDA. I'll give you another problem that might help. Let P, Q, R, and S denote any four integers. What is the sum of P, Q, R, and S? (P + Q + R + S.) Your original question is almost identical to this problem, in terms of how you might want to think about it. Read this (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorSum.html) and this (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorAddition.html) for more details. In your case, u (from A to B), u (from B to C), etc. are the vectors. So (just like on the mathworld links) the answer is uAB + uBC + uCD + uDA.

Answer (score 0):

Recall, $ \overrightarrow{AB}=B-A$. So 
$$ \overrightarrow{AB}+\overrightarrow{BC}+\overrightarrow{CD}+\overrightarrow{DA}=B-A+C-B+D-C+A-D=0$$
[image]

Comment: can you provide me a link that explains the AB = B-A?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector
or on page 3 of the following book 
http://books.google.com.tr/books?id=9wmR7kDdO8EC&printsec=frontcover&dq=vector+calculus&hl=tr&sa=X&ei=JL1VUpnEG4rRsgaC74CAAg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=vector%20calculus&f=false